# Bug in synonym "top users" link

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, tag-synonyms, top-users

If a tag is a synonym, the "top users" link will be redirected to `tags/<synonym>/users` instead of `tags/<synonym>/topusers`.

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/iphone-sdk/

(Click the "top users" link)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this was fixed a while back.